# Trying to get script to run in an order based on what page loads in selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

So, I am new to coding and I have been trying to get my script to run but as it goes through the pages, it gets to a point where the next page will be whatever Form page loads first and there are 11 possible pages so the order in which they appear is completely random.

I need to be able to tell which page has loaded and to go execute that part of the script and then once done, repeat the process until all 11 have been completed.

I am using the following method to break each form out:

```
    testRun.testContentDev(driver);
    testRun.testLandingPageEntry(driver);
    testRun.testStandardSMMEntry(driver);
    testRun.testDisplayAdvertisingEntry(driver);
    testRun.testReputationManagementEntry(driver);
    testRun.teststandardSEO(driver);
    testRun.testCustomSEM(driver);
    testRun.testEmailMarketing(driver);
    testRun.testLocalTrack(driver);
    testRun.testWebsites(driver);
    testRun.testmobilewebsites(driver);
```

I then have each one of those broken out using:

```
    public void testContentDev(WebDriver driver)
    public void testLandingPageEntry(WebDriver driver)
    public void testStandardSMMEntry(WebDriver driver)
    public void testDisplayAdvertisingEntry(WebDriver driver)
    public void testReputationManagementEntry(WebDriver driver)
    public void teststandardSEO(WebDriver driver)
    public void testCustomSEM(WebDriver driver)
    public void testEmailMarketing(WebDriver driver)
    public void testLocalTrack(WebDriver driver)
    public void testWebsites(WebDriver driver)
    public void testmobilewebsites(WebDriver driver)
```

One of the developers inserted a hidden input field that pulls the page information into JSON format in which there is a task name that is specific to each one. The only thing that I know of for sure that is different for each page is found in this hidden input. The taskName is the big difference and references each page specificallly. This is the HTML code:

```
   <input type="hidden" value="
{
"formType":"taskExecutuion",
"orderId":"XXXXXX",
"userId":"XXXX",
"assignee‌​Id":"XXXX",
"taskId":"4649367",
"taskName":"Landing Page Form Entry",
"taskDisplayName":"Landing Page Form for: blank Order ID: XXXXXX",
"rootProcessName":"Atlas - Create New Order",
"rootProcessVersion":"3.0.2",
"rootProcessId":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"taskP‌rocessName":"LE_Landing_Page_Entry",
"taskProcessVersion":"0.10",
"taskProcessId":"‌​XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}"
 name="atlas-testing-symbols" id="atlas-testing-symbols-id">
```

The big question is, How do I get the JSON and use it to check to see which page the TaskName in the JSON matches so that it can run that specific part of my testing scripts?

Comment: So, each page uses similar code but each one has specific fields that need to be filled in.  I am building the automation to test it all. There are several more testRun items that come before the others but they all appear in the same order every time.  These other ones appear based on which ever one loads fastest.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just parse the JSON hidden field, determine which page you are on, and then trigger the test for the appropriate page?

Comment: @JeffC: That is what I m trying to figure out how to do. I'm trying to figure out how to use the parsed JSON to trigger the correct page

Comment: I didn't get that from your question. You should probably rephrase to make it more clear what you asking and provide relevant details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good option to

> be able to tell which page has loaded and to go execute that part of the script

is the [LoadableComponent](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/LoadableComponent).  Using its

```
@Override
protected void load(WebDriver driver) {
   LandingPageEntry.load();
   testLandingPageEntry(driver)
   ...
   StandardSMMEntry.load();
   testStandardSMMEntry(driver);
   ...
```

}

Comment: So would I just change the first section to look more like the load?

Comment: You should create corresponding 'load()' methods for each page including the test code in order of their flow.

Comment: So, the big question is, How do I get it to know which page actually opened?  One of the developers inserted a hidden input field that pulls the page information into JSON format in which there is a task name that is specific to each one.

Comment: This looks like an overhead solution to me. I obviously don't know your domain, but every page has unique HTML elements - can you map such one to your tests? If element A is displayed, this is page A.

Comment: What is the point of different pages if the HTML is identical? I've improved your question with the comments - you can remove ém now. I'll do the same for mine, lets keep it clean.